# How do I fetch an int[] of RGB pixels from a BufferedImage using parallel computing?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, bufferedimage

I am trying to fetch an `int[]` of pixels from a `BufferedImage` using parallel computing. More specifically, I am dividing the image into chunks of 64 bits from the width and computing the pixels per section. The main reason why I am using parallel computing is that I am developing a video player and I want to use multi-threading to parse the frame pixels.

Normally, you can easily fetch all the pixels using the following code:

(1a)

```java
final int width = image.getWidth();
final int[] pixels = image.getRGB(0, 0, width, image.getHeight(), null, 0, width );
```

However, in my case, I tried to use `IntStream` and the `parallel()` method to help parallelize the process:

(1b)

```java
  public static int[] getRGBFast(@NotNull final BufferedImage image) {
    final int width = image.getWidth();
    final int height = image.getHeight();
    final int[] rgb = new int[width * height];
    final int num = width / 64;
    final int leftover = width - num * 64;
    IntStream.range(0, num + (width % 64 == 0 ? 0 : 1))
        .parallel()
        .forEach(chunk -> {
          final int pixel = chunk << 6;
          if (chunk == num) {
            image.getRGB(pixel, 0, leftover, height, rgb, 0, width);
          } else {
            image.getRGB(pixel, 0, 64, height, rgb, 0, width);
          }
        });
    return rgb;
  }
```

When comparing the results from `(1a)` and `(1b)`, it seems that almost all the pixels are misplaced. I used the following code to compare the two arrays:

```java
    for (int i = 0; i < rgb.length; i++) {
      final int color = rgb[i];
      final int old = original[i];
      if (color != old) {
        System.out.printf("Index: %d mismatch [%d,%d]%n", i, color, old);
      }
    }
```

The results of the last couple thousand lines [are as follows](https://pastebin.com/7eNWsu7a). There are many more lines following it which show the pixels don't match. For a visual aspect, I ran the code 10 times and displayed the images for it. For a strange reason, the results seemed to vary for each iteration:

[image: iteration]

As reference, the original image looks like this:

[image]

I am not sure where my algorithm is flawed. Could anyone point out the possible issue that I am encountering?

Comment: Shouldn't `scansize` be `width`?

Comment: @tgdavies I'm a bit confused here. I've been told it should be the width usually. In my case, I am dealing with 64-bit width chunks, so I set it to 64. But for the leftover part, I set it to the leftover part. If I set it to width, I get strange results.

Comment: `w` and `h` refer to the region in the image, but `scansize` is just the notional width of `rgbArray`.

Comment: @tgdavies Hm. I tried that and it seems to now have filled the whole array, however, there are pixels that mismatch when comparing. Perhaps I am filling a pixel multiple times somewhere?

Comment: Please update your question with your new code and a description of which pixels mismatch.

Comment: Sorry. I updated the question. It seems that many thousands of pixels are not correct. I'm just not sure why.

Comment: You have `w`, region width, set to 63 when you want 64.

Comment: I changed it to 64 now. I updated the post with the updated mismatched pixels.

Comment: And the offset needs to point to where the region should start in `rgbArray`. Apologies for only fixing this one parameter at a time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code,

```
  if (chunk == num) {
    image.getRGB(pixel, 0, leftover, height, rgb, 0, width);
  } else {
    image.getRGB(pixel, 0, 64, height, rgb, 0, width);
  }
```

The `offset` parameter to `getRGB` is always zero. Therefore, every chunk will be written into the "leftmost" part of the array (the part that is leftmost when the array is interpreted as a 2D `width x height` image), at zero offset. The different threads write to the same region, the last one to run "wins", which varies run by run, row by row, and even pixel by pixel - that explain the different results and the glitches.

To avoid moving the chunk, the offset should match the `x` coordinate (in general, the offset should be the index of the top left pixel, `x + y * width`, here `y` is zero so only `x` remains): (not tested)

```
  if (chunk == num) {
    image.getRGB(pixel, 0, leftover, height, rgb, pixel, width);
  } else {
    image.getRGB(pixel, 0, 64, height, rgb, pixel, width);
  }
```

By the way I recommend dividing the image along its `y` axis instead of its `x` axis, so that the regions being copied by each thread are contiguous. That isn't more correct, but it may be more efficient, and isn't more difficult.

Comment: That seemed to do the trick. Thank you to everyone that helped! And also I'm wondering about using y axis instead of x axis. I wonder why would it be more efficient?

Comment: @BrandonLi unlike a range of columns, a range of rows would be contiguous, which in general is advantageous for locality of reference, and in a multi-threaded scenario also reduces the probability of [False Sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing) (which can occur when two "neighouring" threads write to elements of the array that are close to each other). Perhaps these effects are small in this case, but in general that's why chunks are often horizontal slices of an image (or square tiles, but rarely vertical slices)